# How to check "i" in for loop reaches a certain value

Tags: c++

I am looking for a code to perform some certain action in a for loop when i == some value.

```
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 300 or i == 600 or i == 900 or i == 1200 .... ) 
             // then do some action

          else 

            // do some other action .... 
    }
```

How I can check this  `(i == 300 or i == 600 or i == 900 or i == 1200 .... )`

Comment: do you want to simplify that statement or you just need `||` operator?

Comment: What about switch(i) { case ... } ?

Comment: what about removing the `....` and putting something in place of your action comments and try and actually run it, and then see if its what you wanted?

Comment: your program is valid if you fill up the `//TODO` comments. `or` is a valid c++ keyword but should not be used actually.

Comment: Well, those are all multiples of 300. So, `i % 300 == 0` should do the trick

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use remainder, [modulus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) `%` if it is always divisible by `300`, it will save you from using n number of `||` conditions.

```
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    if (i % 300 == 0) 
         // then do some action    
      else     
        // do some other action .... 
}
```

> The % operator computes the remainder after dividing its first operand
>   by its second. All numeric types have predefined remainder operators, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx).

Comment: the modulus/division operations are very slow, and the cost of doing like this may outweight the cost of comparing when the case size is small

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: We're not in the 70s any more

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit even modern hardware needs at least tens of cycles to do a division. You can check Agner Fog's instruction tables, even in Sandy Bridge, it may take more than 100 cycles to do a 64-bit division. Most 32-bit division takes about 15-90 cycles. In that time you can do much more comparisons

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: More often than not you are I/O bound and this is completely irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

> How I can check this (i == 300 or i == 600 or i == 900 or i == 1200 .... )

Like this:

```
if (i == 300 || i == 600 || i == 900 || i == 1200 .... )
```

The conditional OR operator will evaluate the first statement, if true, the whole statement evaluates to true and the rest of the operands are not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Many good solutions here. Another:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    switch(i)
    {
       case 300:
       case 600:
       case 900:
       case 1200:
           // take action
       break; // done with positive cases

       default:
          // this is the 'else' side of your check
       break;
    } // switch
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The easier solution is to **know** when it's a multiple of 300:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 300)
{
  // Some action
  for (j = 1 ; j < n-i; ++j)
  {
    // Other action
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont think this will be the right answer As per the question